# Xcode - Swift 2 Debug "iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk"

Tags: debugging, swift2, xcode7

I am in the process to convert my iPhone app to iPad. On the iPhone version I don't get any kind of warning or errors however, on the ipad now I get a lot of errors related to png images.

Is there a way to debug and see where this error is coming from using Xcode console? I have been trying to look inside my code but its a big app whit lots of files and classes.

> Feb 20 12:36:50  test app[409] : ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file:
>   iDOT doesn't point to valid IDAT chunk

Answer (score 0):

We also have a large app, though objective c, and I was unable to determine which image had the error.

Our problem was solved by deleting the derived data from the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder.

Hopefully this solves it for you too without having to figure out which images throw the errors.